# Could not find function in pine editor code?

Tags: editor

Add to Chart operation failed, reason: Could not find function or function reference entry

Code here
strategy ("EMA-Crossover")
ema9=ema(close,9)
ema20=ema(close,20)

long= ema9> ema20
short= ema9< ema20

strategy=entry("Long",strategy.long,50.0,when=long)
strategy=entry("Short",strategy.short,50.0,when=short)

strategy=close("Long",when=short)
strategy=close("Short",when=long)

Answer (score 0):

The `ema(source, length)` function is not available in Pine script version 5. So check the version and if that function is available with it.